# Amazon SNS -> SQS message body

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm sending a message from an SNS topic to an SQS. When I'm checking the body of the SQS message on my client, the whole of the message metadata is being sent in the SQS body.

I.E. if I'm sending a message "Hello World" from the topic, my client is receiving:

```
    BenFlowers {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "84102bd5-8890-4ed5-aeba-c15fafc926dc",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:534706846367:HelloWorld",
  "Message" : "hello World",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-06-05T13:44:22.360Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "Qzh0qXhijBKylaFwc9PGE+lQQDwHGWkIzCW2Ld1eVrxNfSem4yyBTgouqGX26V0m1qhFD4RQcBzE3oNqx5jFhJfV4hN45FNcsFVnmfLPGNUTmJWblSk8f6znWgTy8UtK9xrTeNYzK59k3VJ4WTJ5kCEj+2vH7sBV15fAXeCAtdQ=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:534706846367:HelloWorld:8a3acde2-cb0b-4a56-9b9c-b75ed7307556"
}
```

This is a bit annoying as I am having to split the message body up on the other end. Speed is pretty important in this application so i would like to eliminate this. Is there any way to just send the message from the SNS and ignore the rest of the metadata?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SNS recently rolled out a feature that allows you to set 'raw message delivery' on an SNS topic.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-payload-raw-message.html

Comment: Maybe an obvious comment, but the "raw/non-raw" message delivery applies to the subscription, not to the SNS topic itself. It means that different subscribers can use different delivery mode.

Answer (score 0):

SNS limits the message size to 8KB, so there's no way to go around this problem using this service.

You could just send your message directly to SQS queue, where the limit is 64KB.

If your issue is the speed of reception of the messages you put in the queue, you could use SNS to notify the client it's time to make a request to SQS for messages to receive.

Comment: The issue is not of latency. Its just that the message sent to SNS is wrapped up in some metadata and then sent to SQS. So, the consumer of the SQS message gets the meta data along with the desired message. Is there any way we can trim the meta data and just forward the exact message from SNS to SQS ?