# Timestamp in SNS -> SQS message body

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SQS queue subscribed to an SNS topic. When I publish a message to the topic and subsequently receive it from the queue, the message body contains my published message wrapped in some metadata added by SNS, as per ["Amazon SNS -> SQS message body"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898538/amazon-sns-sqs-message-body). Unlike the poster of that question, I want the metadata, as it allows me to generate some latency metrics.

However, I could find nothing in Amazon's documentation or elsewhere on the Googleable web explaining precisely what the metadata means. In [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html), the Amazon docs give an example of the metadata but do not explain it.

Does anyone know what time the `Timestamp` field in the metadata is representing? Please provide a citation if possible, because it is really important to me that my understanding is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time stamp is the time when the notification was published.