# Parsing SQS message pushed by SNS in Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm currently using SNS to fan out messages to a few SQS queues.
Trying to parse the SQS message and was wondering if there is an out of the box message model to parse the queue message body in to because it's a SNS notification.

Is there such out-of-the-box model available for this kind of scenario?
**E.g.:** For S3+SNS events -> com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification

I checked the SQS/ SNS Java SDKs and couldn't find anything similar.
Does this mean the model has to be built in the application code to parse such message bodies?

**E.g.:**
In the below example queue message, "Body" section is a SNS notification where as I'm interested in "Body -> "Message" section. Can the "Body" be parsed in to an out-of-the-box AWS model in this case?

```
{
   "Body": {
      "Type": "Notification",
      "MessageId": "272a7e6b-ea5e-46c3-991f-3563d7cd3f09",
      "Token": null,
      "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:contact-subscription-topic",
      "Message": {
         "type": "contactSubInstantiationMessage"
      },
      "SubscribeURL": null,
      "Timestamp": "2020-10-20T03:54:14.022Z",
      "SignatureVersion": "1",
      "Signature": "EXAMPLEpH+..",
      "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-0000000000000000000000.pem"
   },
   "Attributes": {
      "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1603166057169",
      "SenderId": "AIDAIT2UOQQY3AUEKVGXU",
      "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
      "SentTimestamp": "1603166054040"
   },
   "ReceiptHandle": "ibetdkwxaxkqzjxhrkqtgtbrneyylminkvatzwcounxxnubhdktzzkdqrgzxqsebrdfuuxpwnhbuyhvrcbrwxbfgvgdekcygsgauxtcmouzzhlyqvaazkpqmvmmpixbhnpfpldlgjzcnkmaupbikegthoqvdmxyjcvetpisdzxpxrtsrtxvpbmyln",
   "MD5OfBody": "9657ff8451167353e3d11c492d99d15f",
   "MessageId": "879b6742-8006-bef5-d233-f7b8c8bb33d7"
}
```

Appreciate your thoughts on this.
Thanks team!

Answer (score 1):

The following post describes a way to eliminate the above mentioned SNS metadata by setting "RawMessageDelivery" to "true" for the subscription;

[Amazon SNS -> SQS message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898538/amazon-sns-sqs-message-body?rq=1)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html

Marking the issue as resolved.
Thanks.