# AWS sample test json for an SQS message with SNS notifications in it, to hit a lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am running into some trouble understanding how to create a sample test json to test my lambda. Currently the workflow is SNS->SQS->Lambda. I am trying to test the lambda in console with a sample json. I have tried putting SNS message under `"body"` field in SQS both as a json and a json string but facing parsing issues. Have referred a few other SO answers (ref: [Amazon SNS -> SQS message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898538/amazon-sns-sqs-message-body)), but the suggestion was to use raw-messaging option, which my subscribers do not use. Can some one post a sample json structure to test, for SQS records with SNS notifications in them?

**PS:**
Tried below test event (without json string in body). Also tried using json string instead for the body.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
      "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
      "body":{
              "Type" : "Notification",
              "MessageId" : "84102bd5-8890-4ed5-aeba-c15fafc926dc",
              "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:534706846367:HelloWorld",
              "Message" : "hello World",
              "Timestamp" : "2012-06-05T13:44:22.360Z",
              "SignatureVersion" : "1",
              "Signature" : "Qzh0qXhijBKylaFwc9PGE+lQQDwHGWkIzCW2Ld1eVrxNfSem4yyBTgouqGX26V0m1qhFD4RQcBzE3oNqx5jFhJfV4hN45FNcsFVnmfLPGNUTmJWblSk8f6znWgTy8UtK9xrTeNYzK59k3VJ4WTJ5kCEj+2vH7sBV15fAXeCAtdQ=",
              "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem",
              "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:534706846367:HelloWorld:8a3acde2-cb0b-4a56-9b9c-b75ed7307556"
            },
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
        "SenderId": "123456789012",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "{{{md5_of_body}}}",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Are there any? Please provide some code to reproduce - read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: set it up, then set your lambda to console log the event. then check cloudwatch. Then if you still cant figure it out, use the links Ermiya provided and provide some more context for the question